# angular js equivalent of done function in q library

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I've used node.js q library and there was `.done()` function at the end that would get called at the end irrespective of success or fail.

I researched but couldn't find, can anyone point in the right direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want this the `finally` function of a promise in angular.  You can refer to the following angular documentation on the `$q` promise library in angular.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: can you please also advise how to get hold of $q just like this example `var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");`

Comment: just replace `$http` with `$q`, so instead of `var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");` it would be `var $q = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$q");`

Comment: `.done` and `.finally` in Angular don't do the same thing at all. The main purpose of `.done` in Q is to terminate the chain __so unhandled rejections get thrown__.

Answer (score 8):

You would use `.catch(function(e){ throw e; })` to terminate a chain.

What `.done` does in Q is to terminate a promise chain so that unhandled rejections get thrown. Since $q uses `$exceptionHandler` for thrown rejections (vs. returned rejections) doing `.catch(function(e){ throw e; })` would serve the same purpose.

`.finally` is comparable to `.finally` in Q, which does the exact same thing as it does in $q.

In Q, doing:

```
Q().then(handle).done(handleSuccess, handleFail);
```

Is pretty much the same as:

```
Q().then(handle).then(handleSuccess, handleFail).done();
```

Which is very similar to:

```
$q.when().then(handle).then(handleSuccess, handleFail).catch(function(e){ throw e; });
```

However, since $q delegates to `$exceptionHandler` in cases of a thrown exception (unlike Q or other promise libraries) doing `.done` is less needed since accidental chain terminations is a lot less likely. To illustrate,

```
Q().then(function(){ return JSON.parse("invalidJson"); });
```

is a swallowed error in Q, but in $q,

```
$q.when().then(function(){ return JSON.parse("invalidJson"); });
```

this would result in a lot of big red warnings in your console (by default).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess I should have done more research on the Q library used by nodejs.

Comment: .catch(function(e){ throw e; }) would also swallow the error since .catch is just a syntactic sugar to .then(null, handleFail)